# check if richtextbox contains textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a very simple login form is VB
All of the usernames are in a textfile on my webserver.

So first the program downloads that textfile with:

```
    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    Dim datawc.DownloadString("url.txt")
```

After that my program put the the text in a richbox with

```
    RichTextBox1.Text = data
```

Then the programs checks if the text that is entered in the textbox is also in the richtextbox.
Now the problem is that if i fill in the textbox 1122, and in the richtextbox is 1133 that the program returns a correct response.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `the problem is if i fill in the textbox 1122, and in the richtextbox is 1133...` show that code - thats where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it myself by using this condition

```
 If data.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
```